# Wordpress static pages 'SEO'?

Tags: php, optimization, wordpress, seo

Good Day!

I have a photostudio site running on a Wordpress. It's have a blog and a bunch of static pages. In blog we post some news and the static pages contains info about our services.

We have idea to add some relevant URLs from our blog to those static pages. The links would be acquired from our blog by Wordpress Related Posts plugin.

Example page layout:

```
<Some static text about reporting service>

<URL to post about reporting>
...
<URL to post about mobile photo equipment etc>
```

My questions are:

- Does this method make sense for adding some "live" for a static pages?
- How this would be look from the search bots perspective?
- Would be this a some kind of content duplication?

Thanks for your help!

In case some one interested, here is a URL for the site: http://naiznanku.com

Comment: I have flash disabled in my browser, so I went to your site and saw... nothing.  Lame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are constantly updating the posts that you want to link to from the static pages, you might as well just enter the URLs directly into the static page's HTML rather than rely on the Related Posts plugin to come up with the correct posts.

In my experience the Related Posts plugin isn't that great at finding the best matches and it sounds like you know exactly which posts are to be linked on which static pages so simply editing the HTML it probably better (and easier).

From a search engine perspective this is fine - you are simply linking from one page to another.

You would only have a duplicate content issue if you actually displayed your post's content on your static page, which I don't think you are planning on doing. If you just display a link to the post then there is no duplication.

I love your photo of the guy with the clipboard in front of the model having a drink!

Comment: Thank you for reply, it was VERY quick! And thanks for appreciate our work = )

Comment: I decided to loop frough relative post directly inside page template body. Thank you Steve!